# Is it bad practice to expose back end on github?

Tags: php, github, backend

This may be a dumb question, but I am an absolute beginner to back end code and I am trying to practice building applications professionally.  Is it considered bad practice to push my application's entire code base excluding database passwords, api keys, and other sensitive bits of data, to a public github repo?  Does this set my application, once hosted, in a vulnerable spot? Is it safe if the github repo is set to private? What is a professional way of handling front end and back end on github?  I have scoured the web already but "backend" and "github" just brings up results for "github pages does not support server side code." which is interesting, but something else entirely.

Comment: "What is a professional way of handling front end and back end on github" - the term is called "secret management".

Comment: See this: https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle  You should try to build your application in a way that it is safe even if the attacker has access to the full source code. Otherwise, you rely on security through obscurity.

Comment: @Dai OP wrote explicitly "**excluding** database passwords [...]". Your quote misrepresents whats written in a major way.

Comment: @Polygnome Oh wow, serves me right for speed-reading. I’ve deleted my initial comment reply.

Comment: Is it open source? For anyone to use? Not sure if you should upload a customer's source for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your application adheres to best practices and does not have vulnerabilities, this is absolutely safe, as long as you do not (accidentally) include any credentials or secrets as you have mentioned.

If your application does have vulnerabilities, putting it on GitHub might actually decrease the danger. If the vulnerability is in a dependency you are using, [GitHub might alert you](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/about-security-alerts-for-vulnerable-dependencies) to the vulnerability, making you aware of it and allowing you to fix it. Furthermore, other users might find the flaw, report an issue or PR and help you fix it. Another added benefit is that your code is securely stored off-site, should your own computer become compromised.

On the other hand, a motivated attacker might want to exploit the vulnerability. In order to do that, they'll still need to sift through your code to find it, and then attack you are someone using your software. Unless your software is used by high-value targets or lots of targets, this isn't economical for the attacker.

> Is it safe if the github repo is set to private?

Pretty much so. The contents of private repos are regulated in [section E of the ToS](https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#e-private-repositories):

> Short version: You may have access to private repositories. We treat the content of private repositories as confidential, and we only access it for support reasons, with your consent, or if required to for security reasons.

I encourage you to read the whole section of the ToS, it is not that long but a worthwhile read if you have concerns about the confidentiality of the private repo.

Note that Microsoft themselves nowadays host the Windows source code on GitHub, in a private repo. And many other companies do as well. GitHub has managed to gain a reputation for being trustworthy in that regard.

Imho, I would not hesitate to publish open source projects publicly on GitHub. But if the project is a closed-source, for profit application, the question arises why you'd like to make the source code available in the first place. A private repo would be much better suited for that.

Comment: "Microsoft ....the Windows source code on GitHub, in a private repo." Has Microsoft talked about that publicly? Is there a reference for that statement? (Not to take anything away from the trustworthiness of GitHub as a platform.)

Comment: @Brad Yes, they talked about it around the time GitHub was acquired by MS (I think wanting to put their own code there was also a factor in acquiring them). And just at the start of this months a small number of private GitHub repos of MS was gained illegal access to, and MS was quick to point out that neither Office nor Windows were among those repos. But it has been a while since MS acquired GitHub and I haven't keept any bookmarks around. Its possible they user their own GitHub Enterprise instance for Windows. MS definitely uses Git since at least beginning of 2017.

Comment: @Brad cf. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/

Comment: The GVFS article you referred to only says Windows is using Git, I was aware of that.  My question was about Windows being in GitHub specifically and I don't believe the article says that.  They could be using a server other than GitHub for their GVFS Windows repo, and I hadn't read any articles that identified it as Github, though I know Microsoft hosts a large amount of code on GitHub as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using php, but this also works in other languages.

When I'm building I have all the db/connect credentials in one file, and set each to a variable such as $username, $password ect. and then use an include statement to bring those variables in to the connect file. Then, put that credential file in your .gitignore if you're worried about other people seeing it.

make sure the include statement is before the connection statement though.

for example

```
//credential.php
$username = 'usernameExample'
$password = 'passwordExample'

//then in your connect file

//connect.php
include 'credential.php'

//put a try block here
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
 /put a catch block here
```

for the gitignore, just put make a file and name it .gitignore and put credential.php in

Comment: This is what I've done.  I have a file named config.php in the root of my directory that returns the sensitive credentials as an array.  I am then using a .gitignore to avoid tracking the file.  Is every other bit of code though, safe for public viewing?

Comment: "Safe" is a loaded term. I would keep your repo private unless you have a reason not to. Others have pointed out how an attacker could evaluate your code to find a vulnerability (and then presumably exploit it). Or imagine a competitor cloning your repo and sparing themselves the pain of having to write their own app: that may or may not be a problem depending on your business model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a short answer for this.

A lot depends on the code quality itself. If you don't use prepared statements to access a database, someone who might want to attack your backend site will probably find an easy way in. If you use prepared statements properly, they probably won't even bother with sql injection attacks.

But the main reason businesses keep their code private is that it is considered sensitive data, just like passwords and api keys. A competitor could simply copy your code if it is in a public repository, then maybe tinker the layout a bit, and be operational within a week with something that took you a year to build, improve and expand.

Still, even when you keep the code private, you should still treat it as if it were public. That means you need to make sure things like passwords and api keys do not end up in the repository.

Also keep in mind that it is hard to delete files from a git repository after they have been committed. If a file is committed in commit 123456 and then deleted in commit abcdef, it is still present in the commit history.